# Can I initialize a useState in a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, spreadsheet

I use a react module that manages the use of spreadsheets:
react-spreadsheet https://github.com/iddan/react-spreadsheet/

In my project, I need several spreadsheets, and therefore several tables that the user can add, modify, delete on the fly

At the beginning, I wanted to use a big useState variable where the data arrays would be concentrated in the form : stateData = [ [...arrays], [...arrays...] ]

But the module, which uses an OnChange function taking as value the setData, seems to bug when my stateData variable contains different arrays.

```
<Spreadsheet key={index} className='table' columnLabels={stringLabelCol} rowLabels={stringLabelRow} data={stateData[index]} onChange={setData}  />
```

As I can't manage everything in one UseState with this module,
is it possible to create a series of UseState inside a loop ?

It seems to me that it is a bad practice but I am really blocked
Thank you for reading my text... :/

Comment: No. There is a golden rule that react hooks can not be in loops

Comment: You can `useState([ [arr1], [arr2], ... ])` if that works for your use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your code and your comment, I'm assuming that:

- You have one `useState` named `data` with ALL your data in it
- You have multiple spreadsheets
- For each spreadsheet, you want to pass the `sheetData` and the `onChange` that updates it

The issue in your code is that you're setting `onChange={setData}`, meaning any change will override the WHOLE data object, not just the targeted index.

What you want to do is have your `onChange` function be a function that updates only the right part of your state. So you'd do it like so:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const updateSheetData = (index, sheetData) => {
  // We clone the current state
  const tempData = [...data]
  // We update the right index
  tempData[index] = sheetData
  // This is now the new state
  setData(tempData)
}

//...
// the onChange function for our component will use our custom function
<Spreadsheet 
  key={index} 
  className='table' 
  columnLabels={stringLabelCol} 
  rowLabels={stringLabelRow} 
  data={stateData[index]} 
  onChange={(newData) => updateSheetData(index, newData)}  
/>
```

Then you'll also have to correctly update the `data` state whenever you add a new sheet or remove a sheet, to make sure the index are updated. But the idea is the same

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it and it seems to work for now.
I thank you so much because I was really stuck, I am a beginner on react. Thanks